# How to clean Cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra

1. I had setup a 50 node Apache Cassandra cluster
2. I took one node and wanted to install DSE on it and make is a single node DSE cluster
3. I have removed /var/lib/cassandra and /var/log/cassandra
4. I have truncated systems.peers table on the single node
5. When I start dse cassandra on this node, I still see the remaining nodes doing handshake and being added to this cluster.

What is the best way to complete remove any traces of existing Cassandra cluster from this node?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the **cluster_name** directive in cassandra.yaml to a different name to the rest of the cluster.